# can't create the sails api in command prompt?

Tags: sails.js

I installed sail.js  and lift the application it works perfectly in localhost.my application name is abc.I cannot able to create the api in sail.js.I used the command : **sails generate api employee**.
E:\sails apllications\abc>sails generate api employee
but it shows sails is not recognized internal or external command.can anyone solve this issue?.Thankyou.

Comment: Is sails perfectly installed, try doing "sails --version" so that you can see if it is installed perfectly.

Comment: I would like to know if you have installed sails globally? Could you paste the command you used to install sails?